# How to replace a string in javascript only when it's comes before another string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to replace `xx` with `.` in this string `100x100/<name>xx-somename-xxjpg` but only `xx` comes next to jpg.

```
'100x100/<name>xx-somename-xxjpg'.replace(/(xx(jpg|jpeg|png))/,'$')
What I get -> 100x100/<name>xx-somename-$
What I expect-> 100x100/<name>xx-somename-.jpg
```

How do I do it?

Comment: look-ahead is your friend.

Comment: ^^ There has to be a good dupetarget for this.

Comment: See the linked question (there are lots, that may or may not be the best one), basically it's `xx(?=jpg|jpeg|png)`. The `(?=___)` is the lookahead.

Answer (score -2):

```js
'100x100/<name>xx-somename-xxjpg'.replace(/(xx)(?=jpg|jpeg|png)/,'.')
```